# Jooq snowflake copy command vendor specific function

Tags: jooq

Has anyone implemented the COPY command for snowflake in JOOQ using sql templating or some other method? I couldn't find anything out there. I saw a question about it on JOOQ's github page, but it appears there are no current plans to support the COPY command as it is a vendor specific function.
If there's nothing out there, perhaps some tips on the best way to support it. There is quite a bit of syntax surrounding it with all the different options.

Comment: What's your expectation here? Do you want to map the entire functionality of this command to your own DSL?

Comment: @LukasEder, in an ideal world, but I think the main goal is: COPY INTO (stage/table) FROM (stage/table/query). Then some way to add the arbitrary config clauses at the end. I would assume that's the easier part. I'm just not sure how to pull that all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that some middle ground will be optimal for you here to achieve dynamic `COPY` statement support. Of course, you could implement a full-fledged, jOOQ-style mini-DSL to support `COPY`. [Here's the main idea behind jOOQ's fluent API design](https://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/05/the-java-fluent-api-designer-crash-course/). But I think that's probably overkill for the most common use-cases.

[Leveraging plain SQL templating](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/03/05/using-java-13-text-blocks-for-plain-sql-with-jooq/) with some overloads might be enough. [Looking at the Snowflake manual section about `COPY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html), this might be a minimal solution:

```java
public static Query copy(
    DSLContext ctx,
    Table<?> into,
    QueryPart from,
    List<String> files
) {
    return ctx.query("copy into {0} from {1} files = ({2})", 
        table, 
        from,
        DSL.list(files.stream().map(DSL::inline).toList())
    );
```

Of course, you can make this as versatile and dynamic as you need, providing more overloads, or again, offering some builder API or even a DSL. Check out also [`CustomQueryPart`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/CustomQueryPart.html) and other [custom syntax elements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/), for when string templating is not enough.

Comment: Thanks. Using CustomQueryPart made it a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

I took this further and implemented a DSL, for the specific syntax of: `COPY INTO <table/stage> FROM (SELECT FROM <table/stage>)...` which is our use-case.
Below is the main code of the DSL, slightly simplified. You'll see references to various custom elements whose impl is not shown, mostly they extend `CustomQueryPart`.

Note that it's in **Scala** - apologies in advance if you are unfamiliar. When I find the time I'll edit and convert to Java:

```scala
trait SnowflakeDSLContext extends DSLContext {
    def copyInto[R <: Record, T1, T2](table: Table[R],
                                      f1: Field[T1],
                                      f2: Field[T2]) : CopyIntoFromStep2[R, T1, T2]
}


class SnowflakeDSLContextImpl(config: Configuration)
    extends DefaultDSLContext(config) with SnowflakeDSLContext {

    def copyInto[R <: Record, T1, T2](table: Table[R], 
                                      f1: Field[T1],
                                      f2: Field[T2]): CopyIntoFromStep2[R, T1, T2] =
        new CopyIntoImpl[R, T1, T2](this, table, Seq(f1, f2))
 
   
trait CopyIntoFromStep2[R <: Record, T1, T2] {
    def from(select: Select[_ <: Record2[T1, T2]]): CopyIntoParametersStep
}


trait CopyIntoParametersStep extends CopyIntoFinalStep {
    def fileFormat(formatType: FileFormatType,
                   maybeComprType: Option[CompressionType] = None): CopyIntoParametersStep

    def purge(enabled: Boolean): CopyIntoParametersStep
}


trait CopyIntoFinalStep {
    def fetchResults(): Seq[CopyIntoResult]
}

// This is the main class which "does the trick" 
// by accumulating the query parts and building the final query
case class CopyIntoImpl[R <: Record, T1, T2](
    dslContext: DSLContext,
    table: Table[R],
    fields: Seq[Field[_]],
    maybeSelect: Option[Select[_ <: Record2[T1, T2]]] = None,
    maybeFileFormat: Option[FileFormat] = None,
    copyOptions: Seq[SingleValueParam[_]] = Nil
) extends CopyIntoFromStep2[R, T1, T2] with CopyIntoParametersStep {

    override def from(select: Select[_ <: Record2[T1, T2]]): CopyIntoParametersStep = {
        copy(maybeSelect = Some(select))
    }

    override def fileFormat(formatType: FileFormatType,
                            maybeCompr: Option[CompressionType] = None): CopyIntoParametersStep = {
        copy(maybeFileFormat = Some(FileFormat(formatType, maybeCompr)))
    }

    override def purge(enabled: Boolean): CopyIntoParametersStep =
        copy(copyOptions = copyOptions :+ Purge(enabled))

    override def fetchResults(): Seq[CopyIntoResult] = {
        dslContext.resultQuery("COPY INTO {0} {1} FROM ({2}) {3} {4}",
                               table,
                               UnqualifiedFieldList(fields),
                               maybeSelect.getOrElse(""),
                               maybeFileFormat.getOrElse(""),
                               LineDelimitedList(copyOptions))
                  .fetch(CopyIntoResultMapper)
                  .asScala
                  .toSeq
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```scala
val results = dslContext.copyInto(targetTable, field1, field2)
                        .from(DSL.select(field1, field2)
                                 .from(sourceTable))
                        .fileFormat(JSON, Some(GZIP))
                        .purge(true)
                        .fetchResults()
```